# click the specific link using capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, capybara

I have following html.haml page

```
%h2 List of available plants

%table#plants
  %thead
    %tr
      %th Name
      %th Description
      %th Price
      %th Action
  %tbody
    - @plants.each do |plant|
      %tr
        %td= plant.name
        %td= plant.description
        %td= plant.price
        %td= link_to "Select", purchase_orders_path(plant: plant, start_date: @start_date, end_date: @end_date), method: :post
```

I am implementing a cucumber step where I want to click the link of the plant according to name. What I have now is this step implementation, where it just selects first occurrence of the 'Select' link.

```
When(/^I select "(.*?)"$/) do |plant_name|
  click_link('Select', match: :first)
end
```

Instead to click first 'Select', I want to find a 'tr' where 'td' plant.name equals to my plant_name and then click "Select" of that 'tr'

Comment: if you need click specific link, so you have to add specific `#id` to your view and then in capybara use `within '@my_specific_id' do .... end`

Comment: but if want just click first link use `all(:link, 'My Link').first.click()`

Comment: I want to find a 'tr' where 'td' plant.name equals to my plant_name and then click "Select" of that 'tr'

Comment: use capybara `within` xpath [GOOGLE IT](https://www.google.com.ua/search?hl=uk&gbv=2&site=webhp&source=hp&q=capybara+within+xpath&oq=capybara+within&gs_l=hp.1.3.0l3j0i22i30l7.588.5026.0.11364.16.12.0.4.4.0.130.1043.11j1.12.0....0...1c.1.64.hp..1.15.989.0.dTdMOiY_47k)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your plant names are unique enough you can do

```
find('tr', text: plant_name).click_link('Select')
```

This will work because the :text options matches a substring of the visible text in the tr element, and then the click_link is scoped inside the found tr.  It could fail if you have any plant name that is a substring of another plants name, or included into another plants description, etc - but that can handled for testing by selecting plant names/details in your test set wisely.  If you really need to test with plant names that are substrings of other plant names/details the initial find can be rewritten using an xpath and the ancestor axis.